# issue with setting an onclick in fragment

Tags: android

Ive been attempting to solve this for the past hour and cant get it to work for the life of me. Its probably something simple but Im a little tired.

Basically I'm trying to set a button in a fragment that opens a new intent showing a map.
I hashed out the intent and put a toast in to try that but still get the error

The error I get is:

```
01-29 21:12:39.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 21:12:39.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2378): Process: com.example.coreoffice, PID: 2378
01-29 21:12:39.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2378): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 21:12:39.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
01-29 21:12:39.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
01-29 21:12:39.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.example.coreoffice.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:43)



  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
    {

    private int     jcount  = 0;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        displayListView();
        TextView t = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.header);
        t.setText(getString(R.string.HF_headerText) + " (" + getCount() + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, container, false);
        Button btmMap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnmaps);
        btmMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.ErrorNoInternet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       <- line 43
                // Intent i = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                // startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set your `context` variable. Set it to the result of `getActivity()`. Gosh these easy ones are always such fun.

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that, I'm still trying to get to grips with Android

Comment: Throw this line in `onActivityCreated()`

`context = getActivity()`

Comment: Thats cracked it. Thanks.
I need to try and get my head around using context